# Incorrect number of questions in tag on question creation

Tags: bug, tags

Number of questions in tag shown when tag is selected on question creation might show incorrect value, if name of the tag is too long.

For example, when attempting to add tag [prometheus-alertmanager](/questions/tagged/prometheus-alertmanager) on Stack Overflow, it shows 72, where actual number of question was 724.

[image]

Firefox 116, full screen 3840x2160, 225% zoom in windows, 100% in browser. No overriding CSS.

Comment: that first line of the tag excerpt seems cut off as well or is that a screen-capture glitch?

Comment: @rene, probably glitch of screenshot. In browser it looks normal.

Comment: I don't think it's the wrong number, I think it's clipped in a very convenient spot. It [looks fine to me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06V9N.png), I can only reproduce that clipping if I make my browser window as narrow as it will let me _and_ I zoom to >= 150% ([here is what that looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0SL3Y.png) - you can see the number just barely peeking out). What browser+version, mobile or not, window size, zoom level, any CSS overrides / userscripts, etc.? The panel you're showing doesn't seem to be using the space appropriately, but it's hard to tell _why_.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, added info to the post. Regarding clipping, that's what I meant but wrong number showing. Sorry for failing on clarity part.

Comment: if there's only room to display one character, there won't be room for the ellipsis, that is how that style is supposed to work

Comment: This is going to sound stupid, but what if you refresh the page? Is it a symptom that  appears after you've resized the window, and goes away if you reload _without_ resizing the browser window again? It seems like the space allocated to the tag excerpt depends on browser window size on initial load.

Comment: There are some tags that are so long that no number or help link at all displays, maybe these two bits should just be moved?

Comment: @KevinB Probably a good direction, since [some short tags also create Jon Skeet symptoms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SzoJD.png).

Comment: @AaronBertrand, no, my browser was full screen all along.

Comment: Ok, easier repro right here, just try to [add a `feature-request-` tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFkcV.png).

Comment: @AaronBertrand, just FYI, I don't have same problem with `feature-request-` on my scale.

Comment: Yeah, I should have said easier repro for me, I would bet it affects many of us in different ways depending on browser, OS, OS scaling, etc.